# How to add folder using pyinstaller command?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
create_product
    src
        common
            util.py
        config
            config.properities
        templates
            template1.txt
        create_product.py
    Python36
```

I'm using the above dir structure. While use the below command:

```
pyinstaller create_product.py
```

It creates the exe file inside the `dist/create_product` folder. But exe file requires for config folder and templates folder which contains the .properties and .txt file. By default these folders `are not` copied into the `dist/create_product`. If manually copied it works fine.

How to copy the two folders by pyinstaller command itself?

Comment: See section [Adding Files to the Bundle](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle)  in the PyInstaller documentation.

Comment: yaa, did it already works fine, Thanks @Xukrao